# Как выстроить структуру классов?

Tags: java, ооп, архитектура

Дорый день! У меня есть тестовое задание. 
Кейс сбора данных:

- Собираем в "Все" записи в которых есть Номер в ЕИС
- получаем из них сумму
- В консоль выводим значения в котором пишем кол-во лотов и их 
  сумму
- создаем файл с текстом полученного результата.

Данные спарсил с  помощью selenide(selenium).
Подскажите какую структуру(архитектуру) классов применить ? 
Проект java. https://github.com/genabitgit/ParseData
Сейчас структура такая:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ExcelDataConfig excelDataConfig = new ExcelDataConfig();
    SetUpBrowser browser = new SetUpBrowser();

    String startDataFrom = excelDataConfig.getData(0, 0);
    String startDataTo = excelDataConfig.getData(0, 1);
    String endDataFrom = excelDataConfig.getData(1, 0);
    String endDataTo = excelDataConfig.getData(1, 1);

    browser.startBrowser();
    var searchPage = browser.openSearchPage();
    //submit search request
    searchPage.entersTheStartDateOfPublication(startDataFrom, startDataTo);
    searchPage.entersTheEndDateOfPublication(endDataFrom, endDataTo);
    searchPage.pressShowButton();
    searchPage.pressAllButton();
    searchPage.pressDisplayTypeRow();
    //store results
    var pagesCount = searchPage.getPagesCount();

    for (int i = 2; i < pagesCount; i++) {
        var result = searchPage.showResultsPage(i);
    }

    searchPage.saveReport();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В твоём случае `ExcelDataConfig` и `SetUpBrowser` могут иметь статические методы и экземпляры создавать вообще не надо.

Вот если, например ты в них будешь передавать какое-то состояние, например, путь к файлу настроек и URL страницы, то твой подход имеет смысл.

И мне не нравится `SearchPage` - ты нигде не используешь `url`. По-идее, методы этого класса тоже можно сделать статическими и обращаться напрямую, например: `SearchPage.pressAllButton()`;

Ещё. `SetUpBrowser` и `SearchPage` возможно стоит объединить вместе. Например, как `SearchPage`. Этот код будет статическим блоком:

```
static {
   Configuration.browser = "firefox";
   Configuration.startMaximized = true;
   clearBrowserCache();
}
```

Ещё. В пакетах не принято использовать большие буквы. Например, `config`, `page`, `report`.

Вообще, в рамках такого проекта об архитектуре можно сильно не грустить.

Comment: Когда я обьявляю ExcelDataConfig статическим , то пишет ошибку Error:(14, 19) java: modifier static not allowed here. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: @Geferson, без кода я не смогу тебе помочь :( Подозреваю, что ты ставишь модификатор `static` перед классом `ExcelDataConfig`, он, насколько помню, в отдельном файле объявлен. А надо делать статическими его методы.

Comment: Причина была в том что ExcelDataConfig конструктор :)